# how to access parameters of a constrcuot of a class

Tags: javascript

I have the below code. the code in `Initializer` I want to instantiate an object from `MyClass` and then print the contents passed to the constructor of `MyClass`. when I run the code it compiles correctly but it displays nothing at all

Please let me know how to have access to the parameters passed to the constructor of `MyClass`:

**MyClass**

```
class MyClass {
  /**
   *
   * @param {Object}
   * @param {String} param.str any string
    */
   constructor(param) {
   this.myString = param.str;

    console.log(this.getMyString() !== null ? 'my string is not null' : 
    'my   
  string is null');
  }

 getMyString() {
 return this.myString;
}

}
```

**initializer**:

```
const MyClass = require('./MyClass');

class Initializer {
  constructor() {
    const myClass = new MyClass('any text');
    console.log(myClass.myString);//displays nothing
    console.log(myClass.getMyString());//displays nothing
  }
}
```

Comment: Well you even documented your `MyClass` constructor to take an object as the first argument, so why do you pass a string instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't access constructor/function parameters as properties on an object (unless, of course, you pass in an object). This line:

```
this.myString = param.str;
```

looks for a `str` property on whatever the first parameter's value is. When you call it:

```
const myClass = new MyClass('any text');
```

...you're passing it a string. Strings don't have a `str` property.

**Either** pass an object in:

```
const myClass = new MyClass({str: 'any text'});
```

...and keep using `param.str`, **or** update `MyClass` to use `param` instead of `param.str`:

```
this.myString = param;
```

Comment: would you please have a look at my updated code? i know run into a probelm of 'MyClass is not a constructor'

Comment: @LetsamrIt: It's not okay to edit questions such that they invalidate existing answers. Stack Overflow questions are not meant to be moving targets. I've rolled back the edit. Re the "not a constructor," you haven't shown us (even in the edit) how you're exporting `MyClass`, but based on the `require` call, you'd have to do it like this: `module.exports = MyClass;`

Comment: @LetsamrIt: Also re that edit: You changed **both sides** of things, and so it was still incorrect. **Either** pass an object with `str` into the constructor and use `param.str` in the constructor, **or** pass the string directly and use the first parameter as the string. Not both.

Answer (score 2):

You just pass a `string` and want to access it's property with name `str` which does not exist in the `string` type. So it returns `undefined` and it is assigned to the `myString`. You need just to use `this.myString = param`

```js
class MyClass {

   constructor(param) {
       this.myString = param;
       console.log(this.getMyString() !== null ? 'my string is not null' : 'my string is null');
   }

   getMyString() {
      return this.myString;
   }

}


class Initializer {

   constructor() {
      const myClass = new MyClass('any text');
      console.log(myClass.myString);
      console.log(myClass.getMyString());
   }
   
}

const init = new Initializer();
```

Comment: would you please have a look at my updated code? i know run into a probelm of 'MyClass is not a constructor'

Answer (score 2):

Example :

```js
class Rectangle {
  constructor(height, width) {
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;
  }
  // Getter
  get area() {
    return this.calcArea();
  }
  // Method
  calcArea() {
    return this.height * this.width;
  }
}

const square = new Rectangle(10, 10);

console.log(square.area); // 100
```